# EntityFramework ObjectStateEntry.IsRelationship -> What is the Equivalent in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am migrating my application to EF Core and found usages of ObjectStateEntry.IsRelationship in the code. Couldn't find any information of the equivalent for this in EF Core.
Any suggestions?

Tried checking the EF Core EntityEntry class for the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever found a solution to this.

While searching for myself I ended writing this code that worked for me.

Not an official answer nor the best approach but it worked.

```cs
private static bool IsRelationship(EntityEntry stateEntryEntity, Dictionary<string, List<EntityEntry>> modifiedTypes)
{
    var entityType = stateEntryEntity.Metadata;
    foreach (var referencingKey in entityType.GetReferencingForeignKeys())
    {
         if (modifiedTypes.TryGetValue(referencingKey.DeclaringEntityType.Name, out var entries))
         {
            var navigation = referencingKey.GetNavigation(true);
            if (navigation != null)
            {
                return entries.Any(item =>
                    {
                        var property = item.Navigation(navigation.Name);
                        return stateEntryEntity.Entity.Equals(property.CurrentValue);
                    });
            }
         }
    }

    return false;
}
```